# Get the values from one text to another text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can you append the values from one text to another text file in a specific place?

one.txt

```
date : 26/04
test_name : Cs
link1 : xyz
link2 : abc
```

second.txt

```
Pending of taking test {test_name} was due on {date}. Follow the below link
                               
X_link : {link1} --> replace with xyz from one.txt

y_link : {link2} --> replace with abc from one.txt
```

Need to place the one.txt value in second.txt in the place where the name mentioned in { }.

output :

```
Pending of taking test Cs was due on 26/04. Follow the below link
                               
X_link : xyz

y_link : abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex:

**Ex:**

```
import re

# file_one.read()
one = """date : 26/04
test_name : Cs
link1 : xyz
link2 : abc"""

# file_second.read()    
second = """Pending of taking test {test_name} was due on {date}. Follow the below link
X_link : {link1} --> replace with xyz from one.txt
y_link : {link2} --> replace with abc from one.txt"""

for k, v in re.findall(r"(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)", one):
    second = re.sub(f"{{{k}}}", v, second)    # substitute value
print(second)
```

**Output:**

```
Pending of taking test Cs was due on 26. Follow the below link
X_link : xyz --> replace with xyz from one.txt
y_link : abc --> replace with abc from one.txt
```

Comment: In the place date I am getting only "26" not "26/04". @Rakesh

Comment: Use `(\w+)\s*:\s*([\w\/]+)`

Comment: Hi, If I gave Computer Science, it's only giving Computer in output. I tried giving `/s` but the other values getting disturbed. @Rakesh

Comment: `(\w+)\s*:\s*([\w\/\s]+)`

Answer (score 1):

Your second file is already nicely prepared with `format` supported placeholders. So the recipe is the following:

- Parse the first file into a dictionary of replacements.
- Read the second file line-by-line.
- For each line, replace the contents according to the dict.
- Print the formatted line:

```py
replacements = {}

with open('one.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        name, value = line.split(':')
        replacements[name.strip()] = value.strip()

with open('secon.txt') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        print(line.format(**replacements), end='')
```

Comment: Need to print the output no need of saving in a particular file. Thanks @Tomerikoo

Comment: Oh that wasn't clear from the question. I thought you want to replace the file. That makes it even simpler. See the edit

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` getting an error if I given any URL in a first file and I would like save the content in variable and reuse which we are printing. @Tomerikoo

Comment: Please edit the question with a [mre] so I can test @manojkumar

Comment: I able print the output using `print(line.format(**replacements), end='')` and I tried store `line.format(**replacements)` in a variable i.e., `cont = line.format(**replacements)` and trying `print(cont)` got an output --> ` y_link : abc`

Comment: @manojkumar well that looks fine no?

Comment: Not able to get total content with `cont = line.format(**replacements)` . only getting an output `y_link : abc` i.e., the last line from the second file.

Comment: @manojkumar because that line is in a loop. You will just have the last iteration's value. Try to initialize an empty string outside the loop `cont = ''` and then inside it do `cont +=line...`

Answer (score 0):

this way you can parse the file. Relatively simple

```
def parse(text):
    lines = text.split("\n")
    data = {}
    for line in lines:
        key, value = line.split(":")
        data[key] = value
    return data
```

(I assume reading file is not a problem)
Replacing file contents would be simpler if you use [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/intro/#basic-api-usage).
Then you can do things like:

```
template.render(test_name=data["test_name"])
```